# How to change color profiles on ssh iterm2 on SSH?

Tags: macos, iterm

mac os x lion;
Using Iterm2;

I wish to change my iterm2 color profiles if I do ssh on terminal.

Can this be done ?

Answer (score 5):

Very late answer, but I've found a way [here](https://github.com/hectorleiva/iterm2-ssh-color-scheme) that I wanted to share. This assumes you're running Zsh and [oh-my-zsh](http://ohmyz.sh/) but with some shell scripting experience you should be able to adjust this to other shells.

I've copied these instructions here for posterity:

---

Create two iTerm profiles:

```
*   Your personal preference theme (can be named anything)
*   SSH color theme (must be named SSH)
```

Go into your `~/.oh-my-zsh/custom` directory and create a new file entitled `iTerm2-ssh.zsh`. Copy and paste the following or copy from the repo:

```bash
function tabc() {
    NAME=$1; if [ -z "$NAME" ]; then NAME="Default"; fi 
    # if you have trouble with this, change
    # "Default" to the name of your default theme
    echo -e "\033]50;SetProfile=$NAME\a"
}

function tab-reset() {
    NAME="YOUR_CUSTOM_PROFILE_NAME_HERE"
    echo -e "\033]50;SetProfile=$NAME\a"
}

function colorssh() {
    if [[ -n "$ITERM_SESSION_ID" ]]; then
        trap "tab-reset" INT EXIT
        if [[ "$*" =~ "web*|production|ec2-.*compute-1" ]]; then
            tabc SSH
        fi
    fi
    ssh $*
}
compdef _ssh tabc=ssh

alias ssh="colorssh"
```

The breakdown of this code:

`tabc()` grabs the *ssh* name after the command `$ ssh` is entered. This
changes the *SetProfile* name to *ssh*.

`tab-reset()` is responsible for when you exit the ssh session to return back to
a profile name of your choosing. **Remember to create a custom profile name and replace the `_YOUR_CUSTOM_PROFILE_NAME_HERE_` with your profile name**.

`colorssh` determines when to change the *SetProfile* name. Currently it will
change to the **SSH** profile when one of the following values exist after `$ ssh`:

```
-   web *
-   production
-   ec2-.*compute-1
```

---

Again, not my code, just a happy user. Thanks for this one, [Hector Leiva](https://github.com/hectorleiva)!